# Caching option for files

Tags: caching, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I have a requirement to develop a middle tier application to get a requested file from HDFS repository. That is pretty easy. But, I'm thinking of a way that how to cache those requested files for further requests in order to prevent querying that file again and again from HDFS.

For this, what is the best caching option should I use?

Please note that, these files are quite large in size. (near GBs)

Answer (score 1):

HDFS supports caching, more information [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/CentralizedCacheManagement.html). Not sure in which version this feature has been introduced.